# Call service methods parallelly and assign response in order in which response is received

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have multiple service methods which fetch a list of data from different servers.
These APIs respond at different times, I want to assign the responses to a variable when a server responds with the data.

My service methods:-

```
GetDataServer1(req) {   
    return this._http.post("server1", req)
      .pipe(
        tap((res) => console.log(res)),
        map((res) => res), catchError(this.handleError.bind(this)));
  }

GetDataServer2(req) {   
    return this._http.post("server2", req)
      .pipe(
        tap((res) => console.log(res)),
        map((res) => res), catchError(this.handleError.bind(this)));
  }

GetDataServer3(req) {   
    return this._http.post("server3", req)
      .pipe(
        tap((res) => console.log(res)),
        map((res) => res), catchError(this.handleError.bind(this)));
  }
```

The console prints data in order of received responses.
I used forkJoin and zip from component to get data, but I receive data in these methods only when all the service methods are executed, but I want a response as soon as any API returns a response.

My component method:-

```
getData(data){
  req1 = this.service.GetDataServer1(data);
  req2 = this.service.GetDataServer1(data);
  req3 = this.service.GetDataServer1(data);
  forkJoin([req1,req2,req2])
      .subscribe(([res1,res2,res3]) => {
            console.log(res1);
            console.log(res2);
            console.log(res3);
})
}
```

What should I do to fetch data as per the requirement?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You may want to try **static** `merge` instead of `forkJoin`. **static** `merge` is imported `from 'rxjs'`. Make sure you do not confuse it with the `merge` operator which is imported from `rxjs/operators`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subject instead and call the next function when you receive the data, something like

```
  myData$ = new BehaviorSubject([]);
  apiUri = "";
  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {}
  updateData(res) {
    this.myData$.next([...this.myData$.value, res]);
  }
  handleError = err => {
    console.log(err);
  };
  GetDataServer1(req) {
    return this._http.post(this.apiUri + "server1", req).pipe(
      tap(res => this.updateData(res)),
      map(res => res),
      catchError(this.handleError.bind(this))
    );
  }

  GetDataServer2(req) {
    return this._http.post(this.apiUri + "server2", req).pipe(
      tap(res => this.updateData(res)),
      map(res => res),
      catchError(this.handleError.bind(this))
    );
  }

  GetDataServer3(req) {
    return this._http.post(this.apiUri + "server3", req).pipe(
      tap(res => this.updateData(res)),
      map(res => res),
      catchError(this.handleError.bind(this))
    );
  }

  getData(data) {
    const req1 = this.GetDataServer1(data);
    const req2 = this.GetDataServer1(data);
    const req3 = this.GetDataServer1(data);
    forkJoin([req1, req2, req2]).subscribe();
    this.myData$.subscribe({
      next: res => console.log(res)
    });
  }
```

[See this demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-alxnmk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)